# Select from 3 tables all information

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have three tables:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|             profile_employee             |
+------------------------------------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | phone | cv |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+----+

+------------+
|   joburi   |
+------------+
| id | titlu |
+----+-------+

+---------------------------------------+
|             job_to_profile            |
+---------------------------------------+
| id | id_job | id_profile | created_at |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
```

I want to select all of the information from all those three tables, I have this query but selects only first, last, phone, cv:

```
SELECT jtp.id, 
       jtp.created_at as data_aplicare, 
       profile_employee.first_name, 
       profile_employee.last_name, 
       profile_employee.phone, 
       profile_employee.cv 
FROM profile_employee 
LEFT JOIN job_to_profile jtp ON jtp.id_profile = profile_employee.id
```

If been through a load of answers here and still tearing my hair out to get the results I need. Can any SQL gurus out there see a simple solution. The potential JOINs required are frying my brain.

Comment: Please provide ([Edit] your question) sample data and the desired result,

Comment: I think it would be something like `select * from profile_employee pe inner join job_to_profile jp
on pe.id=jp.id_profile inner join joburi j
on jp.id_job=j.id`.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case, but tag your question properly.  MySQL and Oracle are two completely different product.  Which one is this for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following using a `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM profile_employee pe INNER JOIN job_to_profile jtp ON pe.id = jtp.id_profile
    INNER JOIN joburi j ON jtp.id_job = j.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You start from the relation table *job_to_profile* and do an inner join to the two nomeclator tables *profile_employee* and *joburi*:

```
select
    p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.phone, p.cv
    , j.id, j.titlu
    , jp.id, jp.id_job, jp.id_profile, jp.created_at
from
    job_to_profile jp
    inner join joburi j on j.id = jp.id_job
    inner join profile_employee p on p.id = jp.id_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to frame it like this:

```
Select * 
from table A T1
inner join table B T2 ON t1.field = t2.field
inner join table C T3 on t1.field = t3.field
```

For example

```
SELECT * FROM profile_employee 
LEFT JOIN job_to_profile jtp 
ON profile_employee.id = jtp.id_profile 
LEFT JOIN joburi juri
ON profile_employee.id = juri.id
```